# Simple Injector Scope for specific LifeStyle

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

Is there a way to define a scope for a specific lifestyle?  I am attempting to implement my own scope that I want to persist across an application, but internally I also create another scope, and then a request to GetInstance returns the inner scoped instance instead.

I thought if I could define my lifestyle as:

```
public class MyScopedLifestyle : ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle
{
    public MyScopedLifestyle(bool disposeInstanceWhenScopeEnds)
        : base("MyScopedLifestyle", disposeInstanceWhenScopeEnds)
    {
    }

    protected override int Length
    {
        get
        {
            return 100;
        }
    }
}
```

And my usage is:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Register<IRequestData, RequestData>(new MyScopedLifestyle());

// i had hoped I could say
//   container.BeginExecutionContextScope(MyScopedLifestyle)
// or something similar
// this is controlled by me
using (var scope1 = container.BeginExecutionContextScope())
{
    // do some stuff
    container.GetInstance<IRequestData>().RequestMarket = "en-US";

    // this is done via the webapi execution scope (using simpleinjector dependency resolver)
    using (var scope2 = container.BeginExecutionContextScope())
    {
        Assert.Equal("en-US", container.GetInstance<IRequestData>().RequestMarket); // false
    }
}
```

But I'm unsure how to utilize my custom lifestyle when creating the inner execution scope.

What I really want to happen, is that my instance of IRequestData used in scope1, is the same instance of IRequestData inside of scope2.  Is this something I can achieve with SimpleInjector?

**Edit**
I removed the fact that I'm attempting to create an instance of an object per OWIN request, rather than per WebAPI request.  Ideally I'm attempting to create:

```
container.RegisterOwinRequest<IRequestData, RequestData>();
```

So that when I resolve `IFoo` anywhere within my pipeline (be it an OWIN middleware, or in the WebAPI part, the same instance is returned for a particular request).

**Edit 2**
Swapped our IFoo/Foo/MyProperty for better names.

Comment: Sooo.... you want `Foo` to have a singleton lifestyle or I'm I misinterpreting your question? You can register it as `Lifestyle.Singleton`. Persisting instances across applications is not something you should typically do, especially not with services.

Comment: No, sorry.  I attempted to make the question simpler, but in the process I guess I removed that part of it.  I'm after a per request type object, but within the notion of an 'OwinRequest'.  Basically I have a middleware that I want to set a property on this per request object, and then utilize it within the webapi section of my code.  Ideally what I was attempting to create, what the ability to `container.RegisterPerOwinRequest<TInterface, TConcrete>()`

Comment: Don't you need a [hybrid](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ObjectLifestyleManagement#Hybrid) lifestyle than?

Comment: That looks like it could work, but how does it get me around the different instance per ExecutionContext?  If my hybrid is a `WebApiRequestLifestyle`/`ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle`, then a different instance would be returned in `scope1` vs `scope2`.

Comment: Does your `scope1` wrap multiple Web API requests or does it always wrap just one `scope2`? Can you update your question and change the rather abstract `IFoo`, `Foo`, `MyProperty` and `foo` with the naming of things for your specific case. I'm hoping this gets more insight of what you're trying to achieve to get a better picture and giving you better advice.

Comment: Correct, `scope1` would be created per OWIN request, which would only contain a single WebAPI request (i.e. `scope2` in my example).  Updated the names in the example to better indicate my goal.  In the meantime, I've gone with a `DelegatingHandler` approach (using a proxy to allow WebApiRequest lifestyle resolution), and this works ok.  I was just trying to understand if it was possible to create a 'per owin request' to replace the 'per webapi request'.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to accomplish with a custom lifestyle is absolutely possible, but might not be that easy, because you will have to store that scope somewhere (probably in the `CallContext`) and need to create a `BeginMyCustomScope` method that creates a new scope and have a custom `Scope` implementation that removes itself from the `CallContext` when `Dispose` is called. I think this is too much work and too much complexity.

The problem exists because during the time you want to set the `RequestMarket` property, there is no Web API request scope started. The way to usually force such scope to be started is to call the `GetDependencyScope` method on the `HttpRequestMessage`:

```
message.GetDependencyScope();
```

Right after that you can resolve the `IRequestData` and it works as expected:

```
container.GetInstance<IRequestData>().RequestMarket = "en-US";
```

I'm unsure however, whether the `HttpRequestMessage` is available at that point in time, so if not, I think working with a `DelegatingHandler` as you expressed in the comments is a good alternative.

In the past, a good way to communicate data across the callstack was using thread-specific variables, but that obviously fails when using async/await models as with Web API and OWIN. So the new way to do this is using the `CallContext`. So instead of using a `DelegatingHandler`, you might be able to do something like this:

```
container.RegisterInitializer<IRequestData>(data =>
    data.RequestMarket = (string)CallContext.LogicalGetData("RequestMarketKey"));
```

And when the OWIN request starts, you do this:

```
CallContext.LogicalSetData("RequestMarketKey", "en-US");
```

Comment: Thanks, Steven.  I'll stick with the `DelegatingHandler` approach for now, as I don't want to take the dependency on `CallContext` (just yet).  As for the amount of work required to implement the custom lifestyle, this seems like a general request (`RegisterOwinRequest`, especially with the push towards OWIN), so I wonder if it would be worthwhile opening an issue for voting on the SimpleInjector site, and see where that goes.

Comment: @Tris: Feel free to open the request on the project site.